# Apache::DBI->connect_on_init database connection unused

Tags: perl, apache-dbi

I have mod perl 2 code that is doing `Apache::DBI->connect_on_init($dsn, $user, $passwd);` in a script loaded by PerlRequire.

But when processing a request, doing `DBI->connect_cached($dsn, $user, $passwd)` is creating an additional connection, not using the one created at child init.  (DBI is used instead of Apache::DBI because that code is also used in non-apache contexts.)

How do I make it use the already cached connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `$Apache::DBI::DEBUG=2` shows that the connection created by DBI has an
extra attribute set; adding that attribute to the connect_on_init call makes the
 cached connection be reused:

```
Apache::DBI->connect_on_init($dsn, $user, $passwd, {
    dbi_connect_method => 'Apache::DBI::connect'
});
```